# How to recreate Android quick settings sliding panel?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-design-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

In my app I want to recreate something that is very similar to the Lollipop+ quick settings panel that everyone knows.

**That is: by clicking or dragging the header, I want a panel to slide down from below the header and push down the existing content**.

[image: Quick settings appear under the main status bar and push down the notifications]

Applied to my app now, the header is a Toolbar and the main content is a RecyclerView showing a list of blog posts. By clicking or dragging the Toolbar, I'd like a panel to appear to show some stats about the blog. Like so:

[image: Dark pane slides from under the AppBar]

I have been messing around with the awesome (but complex) Android Design Support Library. It has great functionality for scrolling and designing the interaction between the app bar and the main content. But the effect is hard to achieve.

I have studied the [`CollapsingToolbarLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html) but couldn't use it in a way that the content is expanded *below* the main `Toolbar`. I have also studied the [`SlidingUpPanel`](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) library but couldn't make it *push the content down*, simply hover. Overall, I'm a bit lost as to how `CoordinatorLayout`, `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and scrolling `Behavior`s should interact together...

Does anyone know to recreate this "quick settings" effect? Alternatively, maybe someone knows where I should look to find the code for the Quick Settings in AOSP?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally taken the time to solve my own problem, after good insights from [Niko Yuwono](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34131873/2291104) and [Hetal Upadhyay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34132048/2291104).

The key was to rely on the `CoordinatorLayout` and to describe two custom `Behavior`s: one for the sliding panel, another one for the main content. I have actually created a library for this purpose as this may help other people in the future: **[SubAppBarPanel](https://github.com/dadouf/SubAppBarPanel)**. [See it in action](https://github.com/dadouf/SubAppBarPanel#subappbarpanel).

Sample code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <com.davidferrand.subappbarpanel.SubAppBarPanel
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:panel_expanded="false"
        app:panel_offset="10dp"
        app:panel_slidingQuantity="85%">

        <!-- Content of the sliding panel -->

    </com.davidferrand.subappbarpanel.SubAppBarPanel>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.davidferrand.subappbarpanel.SubAppBarPanel$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <!-- Main content -->

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Note: dragging behavior is still a TODO.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I created a library called [Toolbar Panel](https://github.com/NikoYuwono/ToolbarPanel) that worked like quick settings drawer. You can customize the Panel by yourself. If you have any question or issue you can create issue in the github or comment in this answer.

This is the demo video :

[image: Toolbar Panel Demo]

Comment: Thanks Niko, this library is interesting. However it drags the whole Toolbar so the Toolbar itself moves and the panel appears *above* it. I'm trying to make the panel appear *below* the Toolbar. So even though the achieved effect is consistent in itself, it doesn't really answer my question :s

Comment: @Dadou Hmmm that's also an interesting addition. Will try to implement that in my spare time!

Comment: I'm starting to think that I'm going to develop the effect myself with a custom View. I'll make sure I share any interesting result with you and submit a PR if possible!

Comment: @Dadou Thanks! will wait for it :)

Comment: In the end I haven't modified directly your code because I have chosen another approach using the CoordinatorLayout. But thanks for the inspiration ;)