# Android Quick Settings like implementation with Bottom Sheet

Tags: android, animation, settings, bottomnavigationview, bottom-sheet

I need to implement custom view just like quick settings available in notification panel with my items. I have done some R&D part which I will share over here. As this thing is to be accomodated at the bottom of the screen so I have integrated inside bottom sheet view. Before that I will add the screenshot of the view of which I need to create similar kind of custom view.

[image: View while the items are collapsed]

[image: View while the items are expanded]

Now this is to be integrated with bottom sheet, so adding R&D part done below with bottom sheet view:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public void initViews() {
        View bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottomSheet);
        BottomSheetBehavior mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(320);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = bottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.bottomSheetRecyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(mContext, 4));
        BottomSheetItemsAdapter bottomSheetItemsAdapter = new BottomSheetItemsAdapter(mContext, getBottomSheetItems());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(bottomSheetItemsAdapter);
    }

    private ArrayList<String> getBottomSheetItems() {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.add("A");
        arrayList.add("B");
        arrayList.add("C");
        arrayList.add("D");
        arrayList.add("E");
        arrayList.add("F");
        arrayList.add("G");
        arrayList.add("H");
        arrayList.add("I");
        return arrayList;
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <include layout="@layout/layout_bottom_sheet" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**layout_bottom_sheet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_down_arrow"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheetRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**BottomSheetItemsAdapter.java**

```
public class BottomSheetItemsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BottomSheetItemsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> bottomSheetItemsList;

    public BottomSheetItemsAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> bottomSheetItemsList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.bottomSheetItemsList = bottomSheetItemsList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View convertView = inflater != null ? inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items_bottom_sheet, parent, false) : null;
        return new ViewHolder(convertView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.txtTitle.setText(bottomSheetItemsList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return bottomSheetItemsList.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private TextView txtTitle;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    }
}
```

Googling through various sites I didn't find any help of how to implement custom or our own quick settings like views. I have achieved what is required up-to some level but need some help to achieve 100%. I need to implement such a view which shows some of the items by default and rest of the item on expansion which I could relate with the **Quick Settings** option available.

Any sort of help would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you check this https://github.com/StackTipsLab/AndroidN-Quick-Settings-Tile-Example

Comment: @KiritVaghela I think OP wants to recreate the quick settings view and have that view come up from the bottom with their own custom items

Comment: Take a look at this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095471/how-to-recreate-android-quick-settings-sliding-panel  Also, you could dig deep into the android src

Comment: Have you ever note, each smartphone producers has slightly different GUI theme. For example Samsung and Meizu?
As far as i familiar with AOSP architecture, the GUI parts of system elements like QuickSettings is part of hardware producers software. Something is written at C++, some another parts at regular JAVA; 
Thus, in order to extend or substitute GUI at that level you should extend AOSP sources and assemble project with NDK tools. 
Obviously, the entry point is OS documentation: https://source.android.com/setup/build/requirements

Pay attention, the Android OS sources is about 32GB.